# Trying to use hiera with vagrant and puppet

Tags: debian, vagrant, puppet, hiera

So I am trying to use hiera to change how I set up the git user.name and user.email. on my vagrant box.

I have this in my default.pp

```
git::config { 'user.name':
    value => hiera("github_username"),
}

git::config { 'user.email':
    value => hiera("github_email"),
}
```

In the Vagrant file I have this (inside the puppet options):

> puppet.options = "--hiera_config /vagrant/hieradata/hiera.yaml"

This seems to load correctly. What I have in that file is this:

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - defaults
  - "%{clientcert}"
  - "%{environment}"
  - global
  - company

:yaml:
  :datadir:/vagrant/hieradata
```

Now inside the company.yaml I have:

```
github_username: 'antonio'
github_email: 'antonio@mail.com'
```

When I do vagrant provision I get the following error message:

```
==> debian_dev: Error: Error from DataBinding 'hiera' while looking up 'apache::apache_name': can't convert Symbol into Integer on node debian.dev
==> debian_dev: Wrapped exception:
==> debian_dev: can't convert Symbol into Integer
==> debian_dev: Wrapped exception:
==> debian_dev: can't convert Symbol into Integer
==> debian_dev: Error: Error from DataBinding 'hiera' while looking up 'apache::apache_name': can't convert Symbol into Integer on node debian.dev
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

I am using the apache module but even in the default hiera.yaml (the one at /etc/hiera.yaml) there was no definition for apache::apache_name.

If I don't pass in the option to puppet in just complains in can't find hiera.yaml and that it is going to use the default one.

Any ideas or suggestions on how I might fix this?

Thanks!

PS: I am running windows 7 with Vagrant 1.6.5 and puppet 3.7.1

Comment: just wanted to let you know that puppet provisionner has this option:
puppet.hiera_config_path  = "../config/hiera.yaml"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your hiera.yaml file so datadir has a space in it:

```
:yaml:
  :datadir: /vagrant/hieradata
```

To help with debugging, I'd suggest adding verbose and debug options in your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
  puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
end
```

Here's what you should see with the bad datadir value:

```
$ vagrant provision
==> other: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> other: Running Puppet with default.pp...
==> other: stdin: is not a tty
==> other: Notice: Scope(Node[default]): -----
==> other: Debug: hiera(): Hiera YAML backend starting
==> other: Debug: hiera(): Looking up github_username in YAML     backend
==> other: Debug: hiera(): Looking for data source defaults
==> other: Debug: hiera(): Found github_username in defaults
```

Here's what you should see with the datadir updated:

```
$ vagrant provision
==> other: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> other: Running Puppet with default.pp...
==> other: stdin: is not a tty
==> other: Notice: Scope(Node[default]): -----
==> other: Debug: hiera(): Hiera YAML backend starting
==> other: Debug: hiera(): Looking up github_username in YAML     backend
==> other: Debug: hiera(): Looking for data source defaults
==> other: Debug: hiera(): Found github_username in defaults
```

This should also help explain how values are found when hiera is doing a lookup.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. I find it a bit odd that a space would make such a big difference, but it works so thanks :)